# what is the best approach to lock the mysql database. no create update and delete opparation

Tags: mysql, database, yii

Actually i am currently working on a construction management system which is built in yii. Now one project is completed and we have to give them data in view format. we guys are planing to transfer their data on another link so they only can view data.

What is the best way to lock the database, or any other idea is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Lock? You mean read-only DB? Or what? Actual transaction loc king?

Comment: Esseks yes i want superadmin,authenticated users can only view records.

Answer (score 2):

Use database permissions: create SQL users and grant them only read-related privileges. You have read/write permissions, your clients read-only.

Exact syntax is DBMS-dependent, but the statement to use is [GRANT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2155015)

Answer (score 1):

The statement opens a database in read-only mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY;
```

Comment: I believe that is an Oracle command; this doesn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use database permissions, but I would do it with PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.  Only provide the users the password for the read-only user account.  You can grant only select authority to the read only user.  However, root will always have all authority to any database on the server, so if they are using thier own server, you will be out of luck.